# Trouble with checking items in list

Tags: list, python-2.7

First year intro programmer.. and coding a (not so) simple Simon Says game.

This is what I have currently

```
import random

    #the items (colors) that Simon can choose from
colors = ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green']

    #A list for what Simon's pattern can be in
simon = []

    #A list for what the User's pattern can be in
user = []

def SimonSays():
#Choose a random item in the list of colors
    simon.append(random.choice(colors))
#for each item in the list, or each color in the list 'simon', print that list
#this is just for testing to see what the color is
    for color in simon:
        print simon
    userResponse = raw_input("What did Simon Say?")

#if the user responded with the correct color
    if userResponse == color:

#IDLE will print.. then add another color to the list, and prompt the user again
        print "Correct, a new item will be added to the sequence"
        twoColors = simon.append(random.choice(colors))
        print simon
        user2Response = raw_input("What did Simon Say?")

        if user2Response == simon:
            print "Correct"
        else:
            print "Incorrect"


#if the user didn't respond with the correct color..       
    else:
        print "Incorrect, sorry you lost."



SimonSays()
```

now my problem is that I can respond 'Blue' for example when first prompted, but once it's two colors in the list, IDLE always tells me incorrect. I don't know how to format the answer, or any other way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint try using ' '.join(s for s in simon) to print and compare. 
Right now you are comparing to the listed print, which will read incorrect every time.

hope that helps